# Scoped search "query not supported"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
2015-01-14T19:52:56.805276+00:00 app[web.1]: ScopedSearch::QueryNotSupported (relation 'schedule_locations' not one of requisition_plan, machine, schedule_machines, schedule_locations, requisition_plan_products, products, product_categories ):
2015-01-14T19:52:56.805279+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/api/v1/requisition_plan_machines_controller.rb:24:in `index'
2015-01-14T19:52:56.754434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/v1/schedules/225/requisition_plan/requisition_plan_machines.json?token=mytoken&query=day%3Dmonday%26machine_type%3Dcombo"
```

requisition_plan_machines_controller

```
def index
    @requisition_plan_machines = @requisition_plan_machines.ordered_by_name.search_for(params[:query])
  end
```

"schedule_locations" is not one of ...`schedule_locations`... huh? It's in the list, why isn't this searching?

I just upgraded ruby & rails to the latest and ran into this.

Comment: I tried another scoped_search and it worked fine, hm.

Comment: Seems, latest rails version is not yet supported: https://github.com/wvanbergen/scoped_search/issues/115